# Why is passing function in parameters of another function is giving unexpected result in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please find the code below whenever i am trying to run this one it's giving some random integer value why is that . Can someone explain what is happening in the output.

```js
let user = {
 name: "John",
 sayHi: function(){
  console.log(this.name);
 }
}
let paramFunc = function(func){
 func();
}
paramFunc(user.sayHi);
```

Comment: Try to debug this code. And look what the value of `this` when you run `paramFunc`.

Answer (score 3):

When you just call a function without context, the function doesn't know about the object.

you need to provide the context, so the function knows what `this` means:

```js
let user = {
    name: "John",
    sayHi: function () {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
let paramFunc = function (func, context) {
    func.bind(context)();
};
paramFunc(user.sayHi, user);
```

Output:

```
John
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the user object when passing the function that will help as the reference of this changes when you are running in another function

```js
let user = {
 name: "John",
 sayHi: function(){
  console.log(this.name);
 }
}
let paramFunc = function(func){
 func();
}
paramFunc(user.sayHi.bind(user));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , I was not trying to print "John" inside the console i was just trying to print what does the this.name gives to me when called in this way . So i just checked why this.name is not giving error  rather it's printing an empty string . Because this is pointing to the window object and by default window object has a name property which is set to empty initially . That's the reason calling func() will access the global this or window which is giving the name property as empty string .